# Facebook Graph API for finding sent request and recieved request

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-graph-api-v2.2

Is it possible to request the user-ids of the sent or accepted friend requests of an user?

How do we specify the `access_token` in the URL while performing the GET request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Friend requests is deprecated for versions v2.0 and higher as the `read_requests` permission is no longer available.

See the changelog: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog